# How to identify PQR (exchange fare) in Sabre GetReservationRS

Tags: sabre

how do i identify exchange type fares in the GetReservationRS when retrieving a PNR using the Native API? I can see the TicketDetails which contain a status code of A (H for historical and M for manual), does this get a new status code for exchange?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a version number for the "PriceQuoteServiceVersion" element in your request. This is nested under the "ReturnOptions" element. This element needs to be set to 4.0.0 (or higher). When I made that change to my requests I started getting PQR data back.

Super maddening that the default value isn't the most current version. Apparently the old PQ Service Versions did not return PQR data. I had to dig through the documentation to find this as it turns out my payloads were not returning PQR data either.

Anyhow, here's the relevant line from the [GetReservationRQ 1.19.0 service guide](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/pnrservices/GetReservationRQ_1.19.0_User_Guide.pdf) as found on page 2-12 / 2-13:

> Customers have now the possibility to choose version of
>   PriceQuoteServicesRQ API. This will only apply when Subject Area
>   PRICE_QUOTE is used in request. Default value for this service is set
>   to 3.2.0.

Screengrab is below:[image]